# Merge two cells vertically and create loop until last row

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I'm currently having a hard time running a loop to merge two cells vertically. In the picture you can see what I'm talking about: I need to merge C1 and C2, then move on and merge C3 and C4 and so on...until there is no more data.

Can someone help me with that? I just have no idea how to create a loop having all the empty rows in between..
Thanks 
Andy

[image: Click here to see the screenshot]

Comment: Please post your attempt, even though it didn't work.

Comment: I would have done that, but I really had no idea how to do that..

Answer (score 1):

Use something like,

```
Dim lastR as Integer

'get the last used row in col C
lastR = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 to lastR step 2
   Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i + 1, 3)).Merge
Next i
```

Where the 10 is how far down you want to go, i is the starting row, and 3 is 3rd column, C.

Comment: Wow, the "step" is a great move I've never heard of before. Thanks for that, works perfectly! 
Is there any chance to find a last row instead of the 10? 
It has to be somehow possible to say the lastrow is where two empties after last content occur...or am I wrong?

Comment: @AndyWeinzierl see here for methods to find the last cell then add 1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

Comment: Just googling 'Excel find last row VBA' will give you the answer, but I have edited the question regardless.

Comment: I know how to find a last row, but not for that case with the empties in between..

Comment: Ah ok, best best is to go from the bottom up, `Rows.Count` will choose the last row then `End(xlUp) will come up to the last used cell.